# How to access the request body when POSTing using Node.js and Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following Node.js code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer(express.logger());
app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post('/', function(request, response) {
    response.write(request.body.user);
    response.end();
});
```

Now if I POST something like:

```
curl -d user=Someone -H Accept:application/json --url http://localhost:5000
```

I get `Someone` as expected. Now, what if I want to get the full request body? I tried doing `response.write(request.body)` but Node.js throws an exception saying "*first argument must be a string or Buffer*" then goes to an "infinite loop" with an exception that says "*Can't set headers after they are sent.*"; this also true even if I did `var reqBody = request.body;` and then writing `response.write(reqBody)`.

What's the issue here?

Also, can I just get the raw request without using `express.bodyParser()`?

Comment: It seems there is something with `response.write(reqBody)`; when I use `response.send(reqBody)` things are working fine... and yes, I use `response.end` after `response.write`.

Answer (score 209, accepted):

#### Express 4.0 and above:

`$ npm install --save body-parser`

And then in your node app:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser);
```

---

#### Express 3.0 and below:

Try passing this in your cURL call:

`--header "Content-Type: application/json"`

and making sure your data is in JSON format:

`{"user":"someone"}`

Also, you can use console.dir in your node.js code to see the data inside the object as in the following example:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();

app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post('/', function(req, res){
    console.dir(req.body);
    res.send("test");
}); 

app.listen(3000);
```

This other question might also help: [How to receive JSON in express node.js POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742982/how-to-receive-json-in-express-node-js-post-request)

If you don't want to use the bodyParser check out this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9920700/446681

Comment: I tried using `curl -d {"user":"Someone"} -H "Content-Type: application/json" --url http://localhost:5000` but it was giving me error "*Unexpected token u*", that's why I switched to the mentioned call in my original post.

Comment: I'm marking this as answer because of the link http://stackoverflow.com/a/9920700/446681

Comment: `express.bodyParser()` is deprecated in Express 4.x. Use https://www.npmjs.org/package/body-parser instead.

Comment: @TheBlueSky the reason why you got "Unexpected token u" was because the shell consumed your double quotes. The same thing happens if you do `echo any"thing"`. The data you are posting should be within quotes to prevent this from happening.

Comment: From express 4.16.0 or above it's possible to use express.json() in app.use() in this way => app.use(express.json());

Comment: More infos about the deprecation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330014/bodyparser-is-deprecated-express-4

Comment: I added slash before quote and it worked! `curl -d "{\"user\":\"Someone\"}" -H "Content-Type: application" --url http://localhost:5000`

Comment: Starting from express v4.16 there is no need to require any additional modules, just use the built-in JSON middleware: express.json()

Answer (score 467):

Starting from **express v4.16** there is no need to require any additional modules, just use the built-in [JSON middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json):

```
app.use(express.json())
```

Like this:

```
const express = require('express')

app.use(express.json())    // <==== parse request body as JSON

app.listen(8080)

app.post('/test', (req, res) => {
  res.json({requestBody: req.body})  // <==== req.body will be a parsed JSON object
})
```

Note - `body-parser`, on which this depends, is [already included](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express?activeTab=dependencies) with express.

Also don't forget to send the header `Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: Thank you, this is the best answer for 4.16+ then. No other dependencies and works like a charm!

Comment: The best/only solution I could find that does not need the body-parser

Comment: I didn't need `body-parser` but instead the built-in `app.use(express.json())`. And then it was the presence of `-H "Content-Type: application/json"` in `curl` request that finally made it work.

Comment: body-parser has been deprecated now so this is the best answer.

Answer (score 45):

As of Express 4, the following code appears to do the trick.
Note that you'll need to install `body-parser` using `npm`.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));


app.listen(8888);

app.post('/update', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body); // the posted data
});
```

Comment: For parsing json bodies it's required to add the following line `app.use(bodyParser.json())`

Comment: @cml.co is there any reason `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })` is _also_ required? I am posting a rather complex document as JSON in the request, and `extended: false` did not work. Only when I set it to true, the request is correctly parsed.

Comment: Just a note. Had to use `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));` AND `app.use(bodyParser.json())` to get json data on an AWS Linux server setup with NodeJS and Express.

Answer (score 40):

For 2019, you don't need to install `body-parser`.

You can use:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.listen(8888);
app.post('/update', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body); // the posted data
});
```

Answer (score 37):

You should not use `body-parser` it is deprecated. Try this instead

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.use(express.json()) //Notice express.json middleware
```

The `app.use()` function is used to mount the specified middleware function(s) at the path which is being specified. It is mostly used to set up middleware for your application.

Now to access the body just do the following

```js
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)
})
```

Answer (score 27):

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json())

var port = 9000;

app.post('/post/data', function(req, res) {
    console.log('receiving data...');
    console.log('body is ',req.body);
    res.send(req.body);
});

// start the server
app.listen(port);
console.log('Server started! At http://localhost:' + port);
```

This will help you. I assume you are sending body in json.

Comment: I always forget to add the bodyParser.json() bit x_x thanks!

Answer (score 13):

This can be achieved without `body-parser` dependency as well, listen to `request:data` and `request:end` and return the response on end of request, refer below code sample. ref:https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/#request-body

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer(express.logger());

app.post('/', function(request, response) {

    // push the data to body
    var body = [];
    request.on('data', (chunk) => {
      body.push(chunk);
    }).on('end', () => {
      // on end of data, perform necessary action
      body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
      response.write(request.body.user);
      response.end();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 10):

In my case, I was missing to **set the header**:

`"Content-Type: application/json"`

Comment: It was also my case. Other than this, I had to send the payload with `JSON.stringify`. Otherwise I got a `400 Bad Request` response.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
response.write(JSON.stringify(request.body));
```

That will take the object which `bodyParser` has created for you and turn it back into a string and write it to the response. If you want the exact request body (with the same whitespace, etc), you will need `data` and `end` listeners attached to the request before and build up the string chunk by chunk as you can see in the [json parsing source code from connect](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/json.js#L50).

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer only works for a body that is compatible with the JSON format. In general, the body can be accessed using

```
app.use(
  Express.raw({
    inflate: true,
    limit: '50mb',
    type: () => true, // this matches all content types
  })
);
```

like posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69227838/2801669). The `req.body` has a `Buffer` type and can be converted into the desired format.

For example into a string via:

```
let body = req.body.toString()
```

Or into JSON via:

```
let body = req.body.toJSON();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're lazy enough to read chunks of post data.
you could simply paste below lines 
to read json.

Below is for TypeScript similar can be done for JS as well.

**app.ts**

```
 import bodyParser from "body-parser";
 // support application/json type post data
 this.app.use(bodyParser.json());
 // support application/x-www-form-urlencoded post data
 this.app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

In one of your any controller which receives POST call use as shown below

**userController.ts**

```
 public async POSTUser(_req: Request, _res: Response) {
   try {
          const onRecord = <UserModel>_req.body;
           /* Your business logic */
           _res.status(201).send("User Created");
        }
    else{
           _res.status(500).send("Server error");
           }        
   };
```

> _req.body should be parsing you json data into your TS Model.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're trying to encourage or discourage people to use your answer by calling them lazy :)

Comment: Could not figure out how to access my custom body params using `@types/express` for hours. You saved me with that `<UserModel>_req.body`!

Answer (score 3):

I'm absolutely new to JS and ES, but what seems to work for me is just this:

```
JSON.stringify(req.body)
```

Let me know if there's anything wrong with it!

Comment: exactly what i needed

Answer (score 3):

Install Body Parser by below command

```
$ npm install --save body-parser
```

Configure Body Parser

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser);
app.use(bodyParser.json()); //Make sure u have added this line
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Comment: body-parser is now deprecated

Answer (score 3):

Note that if you put your request with a form the `Content-type` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
You could use a middleware, as of **Express 4.16**, like `app.use(express.json())` but in this way doesn't work because it expects `application\json`: in that case to change the content-type of your POST request you have to use Ajax.
Another way is to use another middleware like that:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

where the content-type is the same of the form by default.

Answer (score 2):

for people who dont want to use express JSON middleware because they need to be more flexible: you can use the raw nodejs api for it.

How to call it:

```js
const body = await getBody(request);
```

the function:

```js
function getBody(request) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const bodyParts = [];

    request.on('error', (error) => {
      console.log(error);
      reject(error);
    })
    
    request.on('data', (chunk) => {
      bodyParts.push(chunk);
    })
    
    request.on('end', () => {
      const body = Buffer.concat(bodyParts).toString();
      resolve(body);
    });
  });
}
```

source, but converted to promise to be awaitable:
https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction

for typescript:
the type of chunk is `Buffer` and of bodyParts it is `Buffer[]`

Answer (score 0):

What you claim to have "tried doing" is exactly what you wrote in the code that works "as expected" when you invoke it with curl.

The error you're getting doesn't appear to be related to any of the code you've shown us.

If you want to get the raw request, set handlers on `request` for the `data` and `end` events (and, of course, remove any invocations of `express.bodyParser()`). Note that the `data` events will occur in chunks, and that unless you set an encoding for the `data` event those chunks will be buffers, not strings.

Comment: that was a copy-paste mistake; I meant `request.body` and not `request.body.user`, and I corrected it now. By the way, the `var reqBody = request.body;` was and still correct and when you try it you'll get the error I'm getting. Anyway, can you please give an example about setting the handler on `request`; I don't seem to find it in express guide.

Answer (score -4):

You use the following code to log post data:

```
router.post("/users",function(req,res){
    res.send(JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 4));
});
```

Comment: Given answer is incomplete without including body-parser module.