# How to make user registration with Node.js and MongoDB (using mongoose and Express.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I need your help. I want to make User registration form and use Nodejs, Express.js, MongoDB(mongoose) and give me very simple example how to make user registration form with: Name, Email, Password and Mobile Number :) I've made mongoose schema and give values like that Name: req.body.name but it won't work :/ In my oppinion I made something bad.

this is my code and if you think it's not correct, please correct it. (sorry for my bad english). this is server.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/addressbookdb');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var db = mongoose.connection;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../client'));

app.post("/",function(req,res){
    res.end("Registration Succesfully Completed!");

    var db = mongoose.connection;
    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
    db.once('open', function (callback) {
        console.log("connected.")
    });

    // Schema
    var RegSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        Name: String,
        Email: String,
        Pass: String,
        Num: Number,
        reg_time : {
            type : Date, default: Date.now
        }
    }, { collection: 'AddressCol' });

    // Model
    var UserReg = mongoose.model('UserReg', RegSchema);

    // Add in collection
    var UserAdd = new UserReg({
        Name: req.body.name,
        Email: req.body.email,
        Pass: req.body.pass,
        Num: req.body.num,
    });

    // Save
    UserAdd.save(function (err, fluffy) {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
    });
});

app.listen(8000, function() {
  console.log("Server is running!");
});
```

and this is my HTML page:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="name><br>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email"><br>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pass" placeholder="Password"><br>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="num" placeholder="Number"><br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="reg-form-btn">Registration!</button>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#reg-form-btn").click(function() {
            var name = $("#name").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var pass = $("#pass").val();
            var num = $("#num").val();
            $.post("/", {
                Name: name,
                Email: email,
                Pass: pass,
                Num: num
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The code is completely written in a wrong way. Please go though the tutorial and check how it's done. https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-mongoosejs-in-node-js-and-mongodb-applications

Comment: What is the error you have encountered? Can you post that please

Comment: May be its helpful for someone who want to read a detailed tutorial on NodeJS user registration with mongodb can read here: https://programmerblog.net/nodejs-user-registration-tutorial/

Answer (score 12):

Maybe you should consider Passport or another module.
But you can do something like this:

```
app.post('/signup', function (req, res, next) {
    var user = {
       Name: req.body.name,
       Email: req.body.email,
       Pass: req.body.pass,
       Num: req.body.num
   };
   var UserReg = mongoose.model('UserReg', RegSchema);
   UserReg.create(user, function(err, newUser) {
      if(err) return next(err);
      req.session.user = email;
      return res.send('Logged In!');
   });
});

app.post('/login', function (req, res, next) {
   var email = req.body.email;
   var pass = req.body.pass;

   User.findOne({Email: email, Pass: pass}, function(err, user) {
      if(err) return next(err);
      if(!user) return res.send('Not logged in!');

      req.session.user = email;
      return res.send('Logged In!);
   });
});

app.get('/logout', function (req, res) {
   req.session.user = null;
});
```

Then you should have a middleware to handle authentication

```
function isLoggedIn (req, res, next) {
  if (!(req.session && req.session.user)) {
    return res.send('Not logged in!');
  }
  next();
}
```

And use it on the private routes

```
app.get("/api", isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
   //Something private
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/authenticating-nodejs-applications-with-passport--cms-21619) how to make what you want using very useful module **passport**. Also you will have a quick look at **Jade** template engine which can be useful in your further learning of creating **express** apps.

Comment: but I don't want to use Jade and passport :/ I want to make it "Native"

Comment: also looking for workable auth example, the sample under the link is not working... just checked out from git , set local mongo and run - no any activity on sighup and login buttons....

Answer (score 0):

check this tutorial...you can ignore Angular and mongojs if you want:
http://www.phloxblog.in/single-page-application-angular-js-node-js-mongodb-mongojs-module/#.Vc20OXW1Gkq

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `body-parser`. Try this in your server code:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser);
```

Please refer the question [How to access the request body when POSTing using Node.js and Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11625519/how-to-access-the-request-body-when-posting-using-node-js-and-express)