# TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined in nodejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I'm struggling to make a function which selects from database based on the id entered in a textbox. I wrote the code, but it shows in console this error and I can't figure why: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`.

Code I have so far:

**Client-side:**

```
function select()
            {
                var id = $('#nr_reg').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: '/id',
                    data : {
                        id: id
                    },
                    succes: function(data){
                        var id = data.id;
                        alert(id);
                        $('#optic').val(id);
                    },
                    error: function(err){
                        console.log(err);
                    }

                }); 
            }
```

**Server-side:**

```
app.post('/id', function(req,res) {

    var data = req.body;
    var id = data.id;
    console.log(id);
    var query = "SELECT * FROM Control WHERE id=" +id;
    connection.query(query, function(error, result) {
            console.log(result);
            res.send(result);
    });
});
```

**L.E:
Function select:**

```
function select()
            {

                var id = $('#nr_reg').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: '/id',
                    data : {
                        id: id
                    },
                    success: function(data){    
                        data = JSON.parse(data);                    
                        var id = data.id;
                        alert("merge");
                        $('#optic').val(id);
                    },
                    error: function(err){
                        console.log(err);
                    }

                }); 
            }
```

Comment: Add `console.log(data)` in `success` and see what do you get in console

Comment: It is not entering `succes`  because the error is in server-side.

Comment: So, you are using body parser middleware? , otherwise you will never get req.body on express.

Comment: which express version  you are using?

Comment: Yes I am @GonzaloBahamondez. TTushar- it says in console undefined. And that's all.

Comment: @Ezekiel you mean  in the web browser inspector?

Comment: No. It console.log the id. And says undefined.

Comment: If you are getting type error, is probably that the error happens before the console log, i think at var id = data.id; because your are trying to access to the property id of undefined req.body , because probably you have some error in the bodyParse usage :(

Comment: Now it gets the id correctly, show the result correctly, but still not entering `succes`. Why?

Comment: @Ezekiel success, success, success :D!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you've `require`d  `body-parser`.
And use `bodyParser.urlencoded`.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

This should be before your `.post` route definition.

EDIT:

Before all this, you must do `npm install body-parser` :)

Comment: Ok. This way it works. It gets the id correctly, show the result correctly, but still not entering `succes` in client-side. Why is that anymore?

Comment: It shows no error. In console shows only the id and the result. But in client-side I have an alert with the id, and it is now showed and still not setting the value of textbox based on what selected. Why?

Comment: @Ezekiel mmm in your client side code,  you have "succes"  should be "success" i think no?

Comment: @Ezekiel : can you paste the value of `data` as received in your `success` callback?

Comment: You might have to do `data = JSON.parse(data);` first in your success callback. You have not set the `dataType` property in your ajax call.

Comment: Yes. Done this, and added dataType. But still doing nothing in client-side.

Comment: First update the spelling of `success`. In your code it is `succes`, like @GonzaloBahamondez pointed out. Then, have you set `dataType:'json'`? And what is getting logged in the console.?

Comment: I've edited the first post to see exactly how it looks the client-side. It is not doing anything after success and that's all. even if the server-side works fine and shows in the console the right result.

Comment: @Ezekiel if you are in chrome, use the inspector "Network" tab , to track what happens with the request/response to the "/id" url

Comment: Not in chrome. Using mozilla in xubuntu. But why it is not entering in that function because the server shows the result correctly, so the query has been successfully ..

Comment: Ok. The problem is that the data, which I alerted in success is this: `[Object object]` , and data.id says: `undefined` . That's why it is not working. But why is like that?

Answer (score 2):

You said your error is on server side? Add a body parser to your express app:

1st Install body-parser:

```
npm install body-parser -s
```

The include this in your app:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.post(/*....*/);
```

Your `app.post` must be AFTER `app.use` line.
Full example [here](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.body)
BTW this is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11625519/how-to-access-the-request-body-when-posting-using-node-js-and-express)

Comment: what about express 4 or newest? in express 4 there's not "express.bodyParser"

Comment: Still the same, you have to register middleware to parse the request body: http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.body

Comment: `Most middleware (like bodyParser) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately` . Why? I have express ..

Comment: As for express 4+ `body-parser` is a separate module.

Comment: @DanielGruszczyk :O Not true you need require bodyParser module .... there's not bodyParser built in with express, take a look the link that you sent me