# How to get JSON Data sent through postman tool using post method?

Tags: json, node.js, express, postman

I'm trying to get a JSON data which is sent as JSON data using postman tool and trying to receive it my post() method.

```
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();

    app.post('/myData',function(req,res){
        console.log("--->",req.body);
    });

var server = app.listen(8080,function(){});
```

[This is the JSON data sent through postman tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bc2E2.png)

I'm getting undefined in my console as
"---> undefined"

[image: Control type is set]

I'm trying to retrieve the JSON data set in my postman tool to either my console or browser

[image: This is the error in terminal]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the request body when POSTing using Node.js and Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11625519/how-to-access-the-request-body-when-posting-using-node-js-and-express)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrected. Please try to run this code.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.post('/myData', function (req, res) {

    req.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log("--->",data.toString());
        res.send("Received");
    });
});

var server = app.listen(8080, function () { });
```

Comment: I have run this code on my machine. It is working fine.. Please check it.

Comment: Tried this also, says that ReferenceError : body is not defined again!

Comment: Sorry mate, i made a mistake in the code, THANK you so much, i got the answer and this is the first time i got an answer through stackoverflow website, Thanks a million!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: And i would like to know if possible how you solved that by using that specific code, sorry im new to node!!!!!

Comment: I am currently working in bigdata and nodejs. Thats why

Answer (score 0):

Add *res.send(req.body);* inside the app.post method.

```
    app.post('/myData',function(req,res){
        console.log("--->",req.body);
        res.send(req.body);
    });
```

Comment: it says ReferenceError : body is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Express usually uses a middleware called *body-parser* to parse the received JSON content. `req.body` will be empty if you don't enable *body-parser* or something similar. *body-parser* is built in for the latest versions of Express. It's enabled like this:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());
```

So the final code is like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/myData',function(req,res){
    console.log("--->", req.body);
    res.send('data received');
});

var server = app.listen(8080,function(){});
```

I've also added `res.send('data received');`, because you should send a response when you get a request on a valid endpoint.