# Access restTemplate requestBody in Express.js

Tags: java, express, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am not able to access the body with express.js module. I am sending request with restTemplate in spring boot application. Following is my code for the request

```
HttpEntity entity1 = new HttpEntity<>(lead, new HttpHeaders());
ResponseEntity<String> htmlResponse = restTemplate.exchange(requestUrl, HttpMethod.POST, entity1, String.class);
```

On the other hand I am using express.js module to catch this request. Following is the code for that.

```
app.post('/get_leadcard', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
}
```

However when I run this program, It shows that req.body is undefined. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11625519/how-to-access-the-request-body-when-posting-using-node-js-and-express) help at all?

Comment: Yes it does. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was missing body-parser middleware in my program. Just by adding following lines it now works.

```
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
app.use(bodyParser());
```