# JS: How can i save a value from a return nested function

Tags: javascript, express, next.js

I use NextJS and React. My `server.js` file, looks like this:

```js
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare()
  .then(() => {
    const server = express()
    var countrycode = ''

    server.post('/', (req, res) => {
        countrycode = req.body.code
     })

     server.get('/', (req, res) => {
        console.log(res)
        if (countrycode == 'DE') {
            return app.render(req, res, '/de', req.query)
        } else {
            return app.render(req, res, '/', req.query)
        }
      })

    })
  })
```

i try to save the `req.body.code` value inside the outside variable `var countrycode` but it doesn't work. I need to take this step so I can check this value in the `server.get` function. If the client comes from Germany, the German side should be returned, otherwise the English.

Where is my mistake? What exactly do I need to change?
Thanks for your answer

Comment: Global variables should be defined without `var` in front.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the request body when POSTing using Node.js and Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11625519/how-to-access-the-request-body-when-posting-using-node-js-and-express)

Comment: `countrycode` is not used anywhere, just assigned. Perhaps it would be helpful if you try to state what you wish to accomplish with your code.

Comment: @JonKoops thanks for your answer, i updated my question. Hope you unterstand me better...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to serve a specific version of your application based on the user's language preference, you can use the `Accept-Language` header which is sent by the browser. This header contains the preferred languages of the user as configured in the browser. For convenience it I would recommend using some kind of [Express middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) like [express-request-language](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-request-language).

In your case this could would look something like this:

```
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')
const requestLanguage = require('express-request-language')
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })

app.prepare()
  .then(() => {
    const server = express()

    server.use(requestLanguage({
      languages: ['en-US', 'de-DE']
    }))

    server.get('/', (req, res) => {
      switch (req.language) {
        case 'de-DE':
          return app.render(req, res, '/de', req.query)
        default:
          return app.render(req, res, '/', req.query)
      }
    })
  })
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, that could be the solution. Can you tell me this using my `server. js` file, how can I check exactly that? I would be very grateful for that

Comment: Yes, I will update the answer shortly with some example code.

Comment: thank a lot, can you use my example code, so i can use your example directly in my project? I'm just starting to learn node JS that would be really very helpful

Comment: Added an example, it is however untested. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, it works now. Do you have an idea how I can set a different page folder for NextJS based on the language? I know that somehow... Otherwise I have the problem and have to check every single page...

Comment: You could create a Map that contains which language is associated, or parse the language tag provided by `req.language` (which is a standard BCP47 language tag) and use it's value as the directory name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181091/discussion-between-niklas-and-jon-koops).

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to be sure without seeing the portion of code where you attempt to use the value stored in `countrycode`.

My guess is that you're trying to read the value before it is set by the function.  For example:

```
var countrycode;
server.post('/', (req, res) => {
    countrycode = req.body.code
})
console.log(countrycode);
```

Here, the console output will be undefined, because `countrycode` will not be set until the POST completes and the function sets its value.  To fix this, you should look into using a promise which will only resolve once the value of `countrycode` has been set.

Answer (score 0):

`server.post()` is an asynchronous function, which returns immediately and cannot assign values to variables in an outer synchronous code block. Restructure your code to deal with asynchronous behavior:

```
app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express()

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    server.post('/', (req, res) => {
      resolve(req.body.code);
    })
  });
}).then(countrycode => {
  console.log('server responded with countrycode:', countrycode);
})
```

Alternatively:

```
app.prepare()
.then(() => {
  const server = express()

  return new Promise(resolve => {
    server.post('/', (req, res) => {
      resolve(req.body.code);
    })
  })
  .then(countrycode => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      server.get('/', (req, res) => {
        console.log(res)
        if (countrycode == 'DE') {
          resolve(app.render(req, res, '/de', req.query))
        } else {
          resolve(app.render(req, res, '/', req.query))
        }
      })
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, your Alternatively works, but the `server.get`function doesn't work. I see always the english page, not the german page... do you have an idea for this cause?