# node js async/await : why i can't get the data ? req.body

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, async-await

i am learning about `async/await` at Node.js to make a restful api and I got a problem in the PUT and PATCH method, where for `req.body` it can't display the data that I want

here's the code: `controllers/users`

```
 replaceUser: async (req, res, next) => {
    //enforce that req.body must contain all the fields
    const { userId } = req.params;
    const  newUser  = req.body;
    // const result = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, newUser, {new: true}).exec();
    // console.log(result)
    console.log(newUser)
    console.log(userId)

    // res.status(200).json(result);
    // console.log(userId, newUser)
},
```

and this code for router:

```
router.route('/:userId')
.get(UsersController.getUser)
.put(UsersController.replaceUser)
.patch(UsersController.updateUser)
```

when I enable mongoose debug, only the `findone` function is active, and this method works on `GET` and `POST`.

i using :

```
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "express-promise-router": "^3.0.3",
    "mongoose": "^5.3.1",
```

i already set bodyparser middleware in my app.js.. but still won't work for PATCH and PUT methods :(

please help me. I'm stuck. thank you

Comment: sorry, I misread your code ... are you using expressjs? have you included body-parser? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11625519/how-to-access-the-request-body-when-posting-using-node-js-and-express

Comment: yes, I have installed a body-parser.. sorry for incomplete information

Comment: @boogeywoogy  can you log the value of  `req.params` and `req.body`

Comment: that's cool @boogeywoogy - just makes both answers redundant now :p

Comment: perhaps the problem is in the client side code in that case

Comment: what does it mean?

Comment: @PlatinumIndustries req.params : i get the id but req.body: is {}

Comment: @boogeywoogy check my answer below

Comment: @boogeywoogy most probably, you weren't populating the req.body variable appropriately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you arent corectly populating req.body with bodyParser

This is taken from the [express website](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html)

---

**req.body**

Contains key-value pairs of data submitted in the request body. By default, it is undefined, and is populated when you use body-parsing middleware such as body-parser and multer.

The following example shows how to use body-parsing middleware to populate req.body.

```
var app = require('express')();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded


replaceUser: async (req, res, next) => {
    //enforce that req.body must contain all the fields
    const { userId } = req.params;
    const  newUser  = req.body;
    // const result = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, newUser, {new: true}).exec();
    // console.log(result)
    console.log(newUser)
    console.log(userId)

    // res.status(200).json(result);
    // console.log(userId, newUser)
}
```

> Take note of:
>
> ```
> app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
> app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> ```

Comment: still doesn't work.. data doesn't change when i tried using mongoose.debug it says "..... findOne..." but i used findByIdAndUpdate method.. it's problem? when i using my dependencies above with mongoose function?

Comment: it's just worked on POST and GET method.. PUT and PATCH not working

Comment: I am guessing that PUT and PATCH are updating the database, thus you must have a value in req.body. You probably aren't posting/populating it (via a form)?

Comment: yaa you right, but I've filled it in the json section,
in postman: body > raw > choose json/application

then in the middleware i set bodyparser.json()

am i wrong?

Comment: try using the `x-www-form-urlencoded` field or `form-data` in postman and enter the values there

Comment: actually I'm following a tutorial from codeworkr in this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1XmwszKUNR8&list=PLSpJkDDmpFZ5rZ5-Aur9WRNsBDSUS-0B9) section but I'm stuck in the sixth part when patching the data

Comment: I have seen the tutorial. You have to set the details to update, otherwise it will fail

Comment: not yet, but as you say. I have to follow the steps appropriately (the tutorial) so that it can run well... cause im still stuck.. so maybe i manage to refactor it.. aaand many thanks sir for helping (sorry for deleting comment) xD

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVED]
finally I got my data from req.body.. the problem is.. I forgot checked my headers in "application/json" in postman..

im sorry guys.. take your time to help my issue :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and tried all the answers from stackoverflow but nothing worked. finally I found that I was sending the data in text-form which supposed to be in json. so, if you're sure that everything you doing is correct, check body section in postman and change data type to json.

Answer (score 0):

Nodejs doesn't recognise the req.body parameters, for that to work you need to install body-parser to your project.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

there is couple of examples in the link.

Comment: add import bodyParser from 'body-parser';  app.use(bodyParser.json());

Answer (score 0):

Did you used body-parser to read the request body? If not, use below lines..

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Now you can read the body by req.body

Answer (score 0):

You can use express.json()

```
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
```

Comment: express? not body parser?