# Request body when POSTing using Node.js and Express is empty or undefined

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, postman

I have the following Typescript code:

```
import express = require('express');

const app: express.Application = express();
const port: number = 3000;


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Server started on port" + port);
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
})

app.post('*', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

For some reason `req.body` is always `undefined` instead of getting the key-value pairs sent via postman. Adding `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));` only changes the body from `undefined` to `{}`.

What could be the issue in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The line `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));` must be called before `app.listen`.
If you are using express 3.0 and below use the following code instead as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11625519/how-to-access-the-request-body-when-posting-using-node-js-and-express):

```
const app = express.createServer();
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

If still doesn't work make sure in Postman that you are sending the data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

[image: postman form data send]