# How to send data to Stripe nodejs express backend

Tags: express, fetch, stripe-payments

I tried integrating Stripe into my React app using the official doc at https://stripe.com/docs/recipes/elements-react. If you could go through this doc, you'll find out they're using a static value as amount (2000).

```
// server.js

const app = require("express")();
const stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc");

app.use(require("body-parser").text());

 app.post("/charge", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let {status} = await stripe.charges.create({
      amount: 2000,
      currency: "usd",
      description: "An example charge",
      source: req.body
    });

    res.json({status});
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).end();
  }
});
```

The `post` API from frontend using fetch is:

```
async submit(ev) {
  let {token} = await this.props.stripe.createToken({name: "Name"});
  let response = await fetch("/charge", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {"Content-Type": "text/plain"},
    body: token.id
  });

  if (response.ok) console.log("Purchase Complete!")
}
```

Here, they're sending the token ID and referencing it in the backend as `source:req.body`.

Now I have tried to send amount from the frontend through the POST request as follows:

```
body:{
  amount: 2000,
  tokenId: token.Id
}
```

and then referencing it in backend as

```
...
amount: req.body.amount,
source: req.body.tokenid
...
```

It doesn't work. And consoling both returns undefined

I have tried many things like removing content-type header and pretty little things. Someone pointed out that I should change content-type to application/json and I've thought of setting 
`app.use(require("body-parser").text())` to `app.use(require("body-parser").json())` but decided to consult you guys first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to post a json from client to express server. If so:

**Client**

```js
fetch({
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    amount: 2000,
    tokenId: token.Id
  }),
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
});
```

**Server**

```js
const app = express();
// if express >= 4
app.use(express.json());

app.post("/charge", async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
});
```

Any by the way `tokenId` !== `tokenid` (in `req.body.tokenid`)

Comment: What then happens to `app.use(require("body-parser").text());`? Do I need to change it to `app.use(require("body-parser").json());`? Or just remove the line entirely and use `app.use(express.json())`?

Comment: If you want to post json from the client you need to support it in your server (parse as json but not as text). And if you're using express > 4 you don't need `body-parser` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/49943829/863110).

Comment: @Cole thoughts?

Comment: :) Glad to hear.