# AJAX POST with jQuery and Node/Express sends empty object

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

#### Client:

```js
$('#send-button').on('click', () => {
  $.post('/send-data', JSON.stringify({ a: 10, b: 20 }), (data, status) => {
    console.log(data)
  })
})
```

#### Server:

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.use(express.json())

app.use(express.static(__dirname))

app.post('/send-data', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  res.send(JSON.stringify(req.body))
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port 3000...`)
})
```

#### Expected result:

On button click, both client and server print `{ a: 10, b: 20 }` to the console.

#### Actual result:

On button click, both client and server print `{}` to the console.

---

Why am I getting this result?

**EDIT:** I am not using body-parser. `app.use(bodyParser.json())` is no longer needed as of Express 4.16. The proposed duplicate question asks about express pre-4.16 using body-parser, and the answers do not work for my use-case.

Comment: Are you using `body-parser`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [req.body empty on posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24543847/req-body-empty-on-posts)

Comment: use `axios`...dont use `jquery`

Comment: @DonaldWu why should I use axios rather than jQuery?

Comment: @MichaelDorst `axios` is more advanced, i see people usually use `axios`or `fetch`..not `jquery`

Answer (score 0):

import `body-parser` and add to your middleware like:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/send-data', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  res.send(JSON.stringify(req.body))
})
```

Haven't used jQuery for a bit, but pretty sure you don't think you need to stringify when posting:

```
$.post( "/send-data", { a: 10, b: 20 })
  .done(function( data ) {
    console.log(data)
  });
```

Comment: [Since Express 4.16 `body-parser` is built in.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49943829/1291990)