# Trying to add a product to list in NodeJS ("TypeError undefined")

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have just started NodeJS, so I'm on a beginner level. I am trying to build a shopping list app with MongoDB, in which user logs in, creates a list and then adds items to that list. I can register & log in and create a list, but when I try to add items to it, that's when I run into this:
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'products' of undefined".
Code for it is:

````
    const user = req.user;
    const shoppinglist_id = req.body.shoppinglist_id;
    const name = req.body.name;

    let new_product = product_model({
        title: req.body.title,
        imagePath: req.body.imagePath,
        quantity: req.body.quantity
    });
    new_product.save().then(() => {
        shoppinglist_id.products.push(new_product);
        console.log('product saved');
        shoppinglist_id.save().then(() => {
            return res.redirect('/');
        });
    }); ```

User model:
const user_schema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    shoppinglists: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'shoppinglist',
        req: true
    }]
});

Shoppinglist model:
const shopping_list_schema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    products: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'product',
        req: true
    }]
});

Product model:
var schema = new Schema({
   imagePath: {type: String, required: true}, 
   title: {type: String, required: true},
   quantity: {type: Number, required: true}
});
````

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I know the problem is with this line:
"shoppinglist_id.products.push(new_product);", I have tried everything on it, "user.shoppinglists.products" etc. Nothing works. Any help?

EDIT:
I'll also post as a reference my add shoppinglist, which is working fine.

````
    const user = req.user;
    let new_shoppinglist = shopping_list_model({
        name: req.body.name,
        products: req.body.products
    });
    new_shoppinglist.save().then(() => {
        console.log('shoppinglist saved');
        user.shoppinglists.push(new_shoppinglist);
        user.save().then(() => {
            return res.redirect('/');
        });
    });
}```


EDIT #2:
I am adding how I am getting to shoppinglist-view:
´´´
const get_shoppinglist = (req, res, next) => {
    const shoppinglist_id = req.params.id;
    shopping_list_model.findOne({
        _id: shoppinglist_id
    }).then((shoppinglist) => {
        shoppinglist.populate('products')
        .execPopulate()
        .then((shoppinglist) => {
            let data = {
                shoppinglist: shoppinglist

            };
            console.log(data);
            let html = shoppinglist_views.shoppinglist_view(data);
            res.send(html);
        });
    });
};´´´

And shoppinglist-view:
´´´
const shoppinglist_view = ((data) => {
    let html = `
    <html>
    <body>
    <h1></h1>
    <h2>${data.shoppinglist.name}</h2>
    <h4><a href="/">Go back</a></h4>


    <br>
    `
     data.shoppinglist.products.forEach((product) => {
        html += products
         html += `
         <div>
         <p>
         <h2>Name of the shopping list: ${shoppinglists.shoppinglist.name}</h2>
         <h3> Name: ${product.title}<br></h3>
         <img src="${product.imagePath}" width="50px" height="50px" />
         quantity: ${product.quantity} </p>
         </div>
         </body>
         </html>
         `;
        });
        html += `
        <form action="/add-product" method="POST">
        <p>Add products</p><br>
        Title?<br>
            <input type="text" name="title"><br>
        Image-link<br>
            <input type="img" name="imagePath"><br>
        Quantity?<br>
            <input type="number" name="quantity"><br><br>
            <button type="submit">Add to list</button>
        </form>
        </html>
        </body>`;
         return html;
´´´
````

Answer (score 1):

This is because `shoppinglist_id` is undefined. At the moment, you derive the value like this:

```js
const shoppinglist_id = req.body.shoppinglist_id;
```

In other words, `req.body` has no property called `shoppinglist_id`. If you print the value of `req.body`, you will most likely see that it is a string. If you are attempting to send/receive JSON data (which I'm guessing you are) you must first parse the request body:

```js
const data = JSON.parse(req.body);
const shoppinglist_id = data.shoppinglist_id;
```

Or even better:

```js
const data = JSON.parse(req.body);
const { shoppinglist_id } = data;
```

Please note that you should always parse untrusted JSON inside a `try ... catch` block, but that's another lesson for another day.

Comment: Tried it, and I get a "SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1". I made a new list, and it is showing in MongoDB as 
{
  shoppinglist: { products: [], _id: 1234567890, name: 'test', __v: 0 }
}

Comment: Any other suggestions? Please? I am desperate, otherwise the app is pretty much finished.

Comment: The error you are getting suggests tat the request body is `[object Object]` which is what happens when you try to log/send/save an object as a string without first turning it into a JSON string with `JSON.stringify`. In other words, you must stringify your data client-side before sending it.

Comment: Client-side is just HTML that calls for /post-product. I have tried everything I can think of and googled, but nothing, "var shoppinglist_id = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));" doesn't work. Except that it changes the error to: "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined". 
I just dont understand the logic. If I alter my user- and shoppinglist-model (and skip product-model), the method in my first post works. I mean if I try to add items (title, imagepath, quantity) to User->Shoppinglist. But when I need to add User->Shoppinglist->Products I'd have to Stringify and Parse and doesn't work.

Comment: What I meant is that the information is lost client-side before it is even sent. In your client-side JavaScript, stringify the data before sending it.

Comment: I am a beginner, so I dont quite understand how to stringify the data before sending it. You can see my HTML on my edited (EDIT#2) post above where the data is sent. So do you mean stringify it in the HTML form action?

Comment: On the server side, can you please do `console.log(req.body)` and tell me the output! :-)

Comment: After I hit post-product in HTML (and have inputed values for a product), console.log(req.body) returns this:
POST /add-product
{
  title: 'banana',
  imagePath: 'https://im.mtv.fi/image/5935814/landscape16_9/1024/576/574d2764d0e46b86a28846de55f6ed96/OJ/shutterstock-17038576.jpg',
  quantity: '3'
}

Comment: hm, what about `const data = JSON.parse(req.body.slice(17).trim())`, that should remove the `POST /add-product` part and parse the data.

Comment: That didn't help.. "TypeError: req.body.slice is not a function".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11625519/how-to-access-the-request-body-when-posting-using-node-js-and-express

Comment: I dont know how that link should help me. What am I looking for in it? There doesn't seem to be anything of use in my case, or anything new I haven't already tried.

Comment: I will tell you this: the issue is that req.body is not an object, but rather a string. There is a key difference between `’{”foo”:”bar”}’` and `{ foo: bar }`. You have a string that you want to turn into an object. This is called parsing. You treat req.body as an object when it is in fact a string that you must parse into an object. body-parser is a middleware that does just this, but you have to look into it yourself.

Comment: Do I need to parse it after calling "post-product" or when posting a new shopping list? I am using bodyparser in the main file. 
app.use(body_parser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));