# Posting form data with Vue frontend with Axios to Express backend

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, axios

I have a basic bootstrap-vue form and I'm trying to post the form-data with Axios to Express.

Yet, at the moment my req.body response looks like this: `body: { '{"name":"","country":"","message":""}': '' }`

I would really really appreciate help how I could fix this issue. I can't seem to figure this one out.

Form:

```
<b-form @submit="onSubmit">
<b-form-input v-model="form.name" required></b-form-input>
<b-form-input v-model="form.country" required></b-form-input>
<b-form-input v-model="form.message" required></b-form-input>
```

Method:

```
  methods: {
    onSubmit (evt) {
      evt.preventDefault()
      axios.postForm(this.form)
    }
  }
```

Axios:

```
const AXIOS = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8081', // I'm running my node server here
    timeout: 5000,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
});

export default {
    postForm (form) {
        return AXIOS.post(`/newmessage/`, form)
    }
};
```

Express:

```
// ..require stuff here

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/newmessage/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the request body when POSTing using Node.js and Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11625519/how-to-access-the-request-body-when-posting-using-node-js-and-express)

Answer (score 0):

**This was fix:**

Method:

```
  methods: {
    onSubmit (evt) {
      evt.preventDefault()
      axios.postForm(JSON.stringify(this.form))
    }
  }
```

Axios:

```
const AXIOS = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8081',
    timeout: 5000,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
});
```

Express:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```