# how to send data from angular to node.js

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-fullstack

i need to pass some data from angular to node.js server. this is my angular postlist component:
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-postlist',
  templateUrl: './postlist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./postlist.component.css']
})
export class PostlistComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  public data="test";
  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.http
        .post("http://localhost:3000/api/book",this.data);  
  }

}
```

my node.js server:

```
const express=require('express');
var app = express();
app.post('/api/book', function(req, res, next){
    var data = req.body.params;
    console.log(data);
 });
 app.listen(3000);
```

i'm trying to console.log the data but nothing happens.

Comment: Check out this [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11625519/how-to-access-the-request-body-when-posting-using-node-js-and-express/49943829) on how to get the body of a POST in node.js

Answer (score 1):

you are missing .subscribe in your call. Change your code to  :-

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.http
        .post("http://localhost:3000/api/book",this.data).subscribe();  
  }
```

and in nodejs just print req.body

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning on printing the payload `this.data`, take `req.body` instead of `req.body.params`.
And also check if you have any `cors` errors in console, that can also be blocking your data from reaching your web server.

Answer (score 0):

in the server, you must change the format of your message to JSON like this

```
app.get('/api/GetFlux',function(req,resp){
  let data = "hello"
  resp.send(JSON.stringify(data));
})
```

at angular level

```
GetFlux():Observable<any[]>{
  return this.http.get<any>(this.APIUrlNode+'/GetFlux');
}




      this.service.GetFlux().subscribe(res =>{
        this.fluxList = {
          data:res
        } 
        console.log("Data from node "+this.fluxList.data)
             //,
      }, err => {
        console.log(" err = "+err)
      })
```