# Cannot read property 'email' of undefined. NodeJS Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, express-router

**Problem lies somewhere in file handling**

**Everytime i run post request the request keeps on going in POSTMAN and i see error on console**

**My Headers in routes File**

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router();
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const Model = require('../Models/Users');
app.use(Model);
```

**Post request in routes file**

```
router.post("/register/", async(req, res) => {
    
    const model = new Model({
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
    });

const result = await model.save();

 return res.json({
            "Message": true,
        });

});

module.exports = router;
```

**Mongoose Schema File**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    password: String
  
});
const Model = mongoose.model("Users", UserSchema);
module.exports = Model;
```

**Main File**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const register = require('./UserRoutes/register');

app.use(register);
```

Comment: console.log(req.body).  It's not what you think it is.  And take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11625519/how-to-access-the-request-body-when-posting-using-node-js-and-express.

Comment: that's just my way to see if my code goes that far

Comment: Hey, I misunderstood your question. i got an answer from that link thanks