# how to change my request-payload from an object to show my contents from a form?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When I get on my local web browser I can see that the "request payload" is just showing me an array with two objects like this [object Object].

How can I fix this so that the "request payload" will show me the contents instead?

ex: `{name: "Kevin", content: "pew pew"}`

```
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const loadingElement = document.querySelector(".loading");
const API_URl = "http://localhost:5000/holla";

loadingElement.style.display = "none";

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData(form);
  const name = formData.get("name");
  const content = formData.get("content");

  const holla = {
    name,
    content,
  };

  form.style.display = "none";
  loadingElement.style.display = "";

  fetch(API_URl, {
    method: "POST",
    body: holla,
    headers: {
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
      },
    },
  });
});
```

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    message: "Hollered at! what you gonna do about it!",
  });
});

app.post("/holla", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
});

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log("listening on http://locahost:5000");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try using:

```js
body: JSON.stringify(holla),
```

to send a JSON string representation of the object

Comment: This worked! thank you! but in the terminal, it still shows as {}.

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66820098/6472849