# JSON.stringify () return object Object in req.body

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, express, object

I have a simple route for testing purposes which looks like this:

```
exports.looseAllPendingBets = (req, res) => {

    let array = JSON.stringify(req.body.arrayToDelete)
    console.log(array)
};
```

I then pass an array of object from my client like this:

```
<form action="http://localhost:4000/user/looseAllPendingBets" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" :value="selected" name="arrayToDelete">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger">All selected = Lost</button>
</form>
```

The bind value :selected is an array of objects like this:

```
selected: [{"id": "61277276d8b2b2000482fc39", "amount": "16"}, {"id": "612772d3d8b2b2000482fc3c", "amount": "15" }]
```

But for some reason when I console.log(array) in the route, it gives me [object Object].

I have tried JSON.stringify() like shown above, and also array[0] and array[0].id but this gives me undefined.

Been struggeling with this for a while. Please note I'm still new to this type of development. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to log `req.body.arrayToDelete` variable? (without `json.stringify` call)

Comment: Yes. Sorry the example should be console.log(array). I have changed it. But yes and it still gives me [object Object].

Comment: hm... what about `req.body` -> are you able to see the value of `arrayToDelete` parameter, or is it `[object Object]` there?

Comment: Yes. If I just log req.body I get [object Object]

Comment: It seems like something is wrong with data transfer from the client or data-parsing on the backend side.

I'd suggest checking 2 places: 

1. Which data is being sent from the client and in which format? (is it a `form-data`, `json`, etc. You can see it in the browser)

2. How the data is parsed before you receive it in the `looseAllPendingBets` function? (usually, in node.js and express you have to have `body-parser` or something similar. Check the link for more details -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11625519/how-to-access-the-request-body-when-posting-using-node-js-and-express)

Comment: Did you try `req.body.arrayToDelete.data` ?

Comment: Yes just tried. It is the same result...

Comment: And this way `JSON.stringify(req.body.arrayToDelete.data)` ?

Comment: The error means that you already botched the value that was provided to JSON.stringify. *The bind value :selected is an array of objects like this* - so you provided an array to text input. What is it supposed to look like? If you want to pass JSON then it should be `:value="JSON.stringify(selected)"`

Comment: Thank you. This solve my problem!