# Trouble with React Form POST request

Tags: reactjs, forms, post, sequelize.js, react-forms

I am having difficulty understanding what I'm doing wrong on this POST request. The POST request itself is working which I confirmed in the network tab.

However, I am only able to post static values that I define, rather than the values from the form fields. Please have a look. This is driving me up the wall. Thank you!

Notes:

- In `TestForm.js` it doesn't actually seem to `console.log` the response as I'm asking it to.
- I receive no errors.
- This does POST to my server, and into Postgres, and I will show below what that looks like when I `console.log`.
- `console.log(sauces)` at the start of `HandleSubmit` does in fact show "sauces" currectly, which is whatever is input into the first form field.
- [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/Younion/new-app)

The React Form Component (`TestForm.js`):

```
function TestForm() {
  const [sauce, setSauce] = useState('');
  const [presentation, setPresentation] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = (e) => { 
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch('http://jyh:3000', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
      body: JSON.stringify({
        "test_name": sauce,
        "test_sauce": presentation,
      }),
      }).then((res) => {
        console.log(res.json());
        return res.json();
      }).catch((err) => {
          console.log(err.message);
      });
    };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="color-section" id="reviewASauce">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <h2>Review a Sauce</h2><br />
            Trying a sauce that is already in our database? Review it!
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <h2>Sauce Name</h2>
          <Form.Label htmlFor="test_name">
            </Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="text"
            id="test_name"
            aria-describedby="test_name"
            placeholder="Input the name of the sauce here."
            value={sauce}
            onChange={(e) => setSauce(e.target.value)}
          />
          <Form.Text id="test_name" muted>
          </Form.Text>

          <br />
          <br />

          <Form.Label htmlFor="test_sauce">
            </Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="text"
            id="test_sauce"
            aria-describedby="test_sauce"
            placeholder="Input the name of the sauce here."
            value={presentation}
            onChange={(e) => setPresentation(e.target.value)}
          />
          <Form.Text id="test_sauce" muted>
          </Form.Text>
        
        <br />
        <br />

        <Button variant="dark" type="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}

export default TestForm;
```

Server `index.js`:

```
app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    await TestTable.create({
            test_name: "test_name",
            test_sauce: "test_sauce",
        }).then((data) => {
            console.log(data.toJSON());
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    });
```

What the terminal displays when clicking submit:

```
{
  id: 100,
  test_name: 'test_name',
  test_sauce: 'test_sauce',
  updatedAt: 2022-12-21T02:54:42.447Z,
  createdAt: 2022-12-21T02:54:42.447Z
}
```

I have tried to change and arrange both the `HandleSubmit` function as well as my `app.post`, but no matter what I do I cannot seem to get the form data from `TestForm.js` to `index.js`.

[image: What form looks like on front end]

Comment: Sent you a pr :)

Answer (score 1):

In your Server index.js you are not using the params you sent from the frontend.

It looks you are using express for you server.

Try doing something like

```
await TestTable.create({
  test_name: req.body.test_name,
  test_sauce: req.body.test_sauce
})
```

Check this: [How to access the request body when POSTing using Node.js and Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11625519/how-to-access-the-request-body-when-posting-using-node-js-and-express)