# How to print the response body (or the request body when POST) in Node.js using Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');


mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/placement-process");

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var router = require('./router');
app.use('/api', router);

router.get('/companies', function(req, res){
    console.log(res.body);
});


app.listen(3000);
```

I am making GET requests to /api/companies using POSTMAN for Chrome browser. But I am not getting any output in my console. What am I doing wrong? Or how would you do it?

Comment: What do you expect `req.body` to be for `GET` requests?

Comment: @robertklep I want to print the JSON object that is returned from my GET request.  For example, 
`[{ 
     "_id" : ---some value----,
     "car" : "Porsche",
      "model": "Cayman"
}
]`

Comment: That's not something that Express provides out-of-the-box, you're going to need a specific middleware to implement that (like `express-interceptor`, `express-mung`, `express-buffer-response`).

Comment: oh ok. thank you. I was busy doing it another way. I actually needed to validate, and I only discovered the word validations a few hours after.

Answer (score 4):

In your code you are doing

```
router.get('/companies', function(req, res){
  console.log(res.body);
});
```

While it should be

```
router.get('/companies', function(req, res){
  console.log(req.body); // req, not res altough it shouldn't be set for GET
});
```

You wanted to print Request body not Response (which is unset, of course).
Let me know if it solved your issue.

**[edit]**

Since you ask to me how would I do it, probably you should note that using `console.log` is not how I'd log something in production. Rather I'd use a logging library like [bunyan](https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan), which is extensible and features a json-only logging. I like their vision that logs should be though for machines and not for humans, by the way they also provide a binary tool to pretty print JSON in a more human friendly format. It's extensible and you can find a lot of plugins (referred to as "streams") that log also to log aggregators and third party services should you need that kind of feature.

Uh, and of course there are a lot of other valid alternatives [out there](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=logging%20library&page=1&ranking=optimal).

**[update as per OP comment]**

I think I now understand what you're trying to achieve.
You should have a look at the response actually `after` it has been generated. Where you are trying to print something you didn't even touch the response object, so it should not be modified (unless you have some middleware doing that for you -e.g. putting some header-).
Refer to a library such as [on-finished](https://www.npmjs.com/package/on-finished) and you'll get the response object right before to send it to the client.

You don't explicitly state your `express` or `node` version so I can only guess, but give it a try.

You could also go with plain node.js [APIs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_finish).

Also you might just put another middleware right after your handler and pass the request next to it with a response set and just log (express router is stack-based so unless you terminate the request you are able to pass in several handlers).

BTW I'd just try our the Node.js API or the library I posted to you.

Let me know if I've understood what you meant to do.

Comment: `req.body` did not work. I need to print the JSON object that is returned. Actually, I need to run the validator, but once I get the JSON object, I will figure that part out later I guess. @LexAgosto

Comment: I just need to print the JSON object that I am going to POST. I am not sure of the methods you suggested. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742982/how-to-receive-json-in-express-node-js-post-request
This is very much my question, but it is not working for me. @LexAgosto

Comment: Sorry I think you need to make it more clear. Are you wishing to print what is RETURNED by your endpoint (that is *the response*) or what you RECEIVE from a client (that is *the request*). At this point it's not clear to me. Also I start thinking you are doing wrong the request. Maybe you're missing the "Content-encoding" header, without it set to "application/json" the body parser won't try to parse any JSON.

Comment: Also notice that you are using a GET handler for a POST request (you're stating it more than once). You shouldn't. Really. It sucks.